How to close VirtualBox when Ubuntu 24.04 is broken?
Cant apt fix-broken install because VirtualBox is running and must be closed. I don’t know how to close VirtualBox.

does this virtual box forum offer any help?

You can use sudo reboot to reboot the computer. That will close virtualbox for sure

You can run killall virtualbox. This should kill all processes related to VirtualBox.

Cool thank you! I will try this when I get home.

Just tried to killall virtualbox and it says no process found

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
